# R: ggplot is giving a wrong and obscure graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm trying to make a graph that shows how the value of a stock changes over time. But when I run the code, the graph that comes up is really wrong.

I noticed that all the dates in the 'plotdata' output are marked as <NA>.

Since I'm new to R, I don't know what to do next.

Here is an excerpt from the table:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
library("readxl")
library("ggplot2")

generate_plot <- function(data, stockname) {
    stockdata <- data[[stockname]]
    dates <- data[["Date"]]

    for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
        dates[[i]] <- as.Date(dates[[i]], format = "%m-%d-%Y")
    }

    plotdata <- data.frame(stockdata, dates)

    plot <- ggplot(plotdata, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()

    print(head(plotdata))

    return(plot)
}

stockmarketdata <- read_xlsx("newstockmarket.xlsx")

aktiennamen <- head(names(stockmarketdata), -4)

plot <- generate_plot(data, aktiennamen[[1]])

print(plot)

ggsave("plot.png", plot = plot)
```

And here is the graph it produces:

[image]

I have tried changing minor details but nothing changed the graph significantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to convert the %m-$d-%Y dates into Date format is not working the way you intended.

```
dates <- c("1-2-2018", "1-3-2018")
for (i in 1:length(dates)) {
  dates[[i]] <- as.Date(dates[[i]], format = "%m-%d-%Y")
}
str(dates)
#chr [1:2] "17533" "17534"
```

Compare to

```
dates <- c("1-2-2018", "1-3-2018")
dates <- as.Date(dates, format = "%m-%d-%Y")
str(dates)
#Date[1:2], format: "2018-01-02" "2018-01-03"
```

We want the 2nd version, so the output is date format instead of character, so ggplot2 will sort it correctly and display reasonable breaks. Your character dates are being displayed for every single day, as text like "17533" -- that's why it looks so wrong. (The 2nd way is also more idiomatic for R, where most operations are vectorized and can be applied to the whole column at once instead of by manually creating loops for each element. More background: https://www.noamross.net/archives/2014-04-16-vectorization-in-r-why/)

The first version doesn't work as you intended, because it asks R to replace each element of the character vector one by one, so it needs to coerce the dates to character data to fit the type of the rest of the vector, and in this case it does so by converting to numeric (days since 1970-01-01) and then converting that to text. So you're getting the same thing as if you ran

```
as.character(as.numeric(as.Date(dates, format = "%m-%d-%Y")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what your desired output is but here's one example to get you started:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

# recreating your data
df <- tibble(
  Date = as.Date(c("2018-01-02", "2018-01-03", "2018-01-04", "2018-01-05", "2018-01-06")),
  NYSE = runif(n = 5, min = 14000, max = 16000),
  NASDAQ = runif(n = 5, min = 7000, max = 7200),
  LSE = runif(n = 5, min = 3700, max = 3800)
)

# plotting after creating the data in long format so it can be grouped
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-Date,
               names_to="stock",
               values_to="price") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Date, y=price, color=stock)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point()
```

This should produce a plot like this (assuming all other options are left to default):
[image: stock plot]

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code, by only putting the stockname in character format. You don't have to do a for loop to change the date formats, and you can select directly the columns you want to plot in your aes() function, instead of creating a new dataset.

```
library(readxl)
library(tidyverse)

generate_plot <- function(data, stockname) {

  plot <- ggplot(data) + 
    aes_string(x = "Date", y = stockname) +
  geom_point()

  print(stockname)
  
  return(plot)
}

stockmarketdata <- read_xlsx("newstockmarket.xlsx")

stockmarketdata$Date=as.Date(stockmarketdata$Date, format = "%m-%d-%Y")

plot <- generate_plot(stockmarketdata, "BTC")

print(plot)

ggsave("plot.png", plot = plot)
```

And if you want to plot many columns, you can use the map() function from the `purrr` package (included in the `tidyverse` package).

```
colnames_to_plot=colnames(stockmarketdata)

plot_list=map(colnames_to_plot,~{ 
generate_plot(stockmarketdata, .x)})

plot_list
```